# MTKTextureLoader freezes the thread

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit, mtktextureloader

I noticed strange behaviour of sync `newTexture(name: String, scaleFactor: CGFloat, bundle: Bundle?, options: [MTKTextureLoader.Option : Any]? = nil) throws -> MTLTexture` method, sometimes (like 1 of 10 times) it just the freezes thread and does not return anything at all, not a structure value neither an error. I have no idea why it's happening and how to make a work around.

Comment: Have you looked at what the other threads are doing in such case?

Comment: @Olha yes, other threads are fine, UI is still working smooth as nothing is wrong